# What should I do about questions like this?

Tags: discussion

(My apologies if this is a duplicate; I searched and didn't find anything.)

I just came upon [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702492/linear-mapping-matrices) question. Apparently (I don't visit Meta much, but I gathered this from my searches), there's an ongoing debate regarding homework and all that. I'm not particularly interested in that—it's questions like the linked one, specifically.

Should I downvote it? Flag it? Or ignore/answer it as regular?

Comment: There is no consensus on this issue. What many would view as reasonable, however, is to leave a comment encouraging the asker to share their thoughts and explain what they're having trouble with; then vote and/or answer as you wish. If the asker is completely unresponsive to comments, or has asked numerous questions with no context, then I strongly consider a close vote.

Comment: @T.Bongers: It's not clear to me there is no consensus (nor is it clear there is a consensus). A consensus only requires "general agreement", not "unanimous agreement".

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12832/dealing-with-zero-effort-questions Some idea how to manage these questions were mentioned here.